# How can I obtain this specific series data to calculate time-to-funding-weighted average of premium index?

Tags: time-series, pine-script, series

I'm looking to calculate and plot the funding rate of Binance BTCUSDT Perpetual and have come across the following documentation page: https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/360033525031

It states:

The Funding Rate formula:

"Funding Rate (F) = Average Premium Index (P) + clamp (interest rate - Premium Index (P), 0.05%, -0.05%)"

I'm obtaining the "Premium Index" just fine, just with "p = request.security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT_PREMIUM", "", close)*100"

However I'm currently struggling with how to obtain the:

"Time-to-funding weighted Average of Premium Index " which apparently is calculated with

"Average Premium Index (P) = (1 * Premium_Index_1 + 2 * Premium_Index_2 + 3 * Premium_Index_3 +···+·480 * Premium_index_480)/(1+2+3+···+480)"

(the funding period for Binance is 8 hours hence the average over 480 minutes)

My exact question is, how do I backtrack to the last funding timestamp of 00:00 / 08:00 / 16:00, then obtain an array / series data of the premium index at each of the last 480 minutes, so that I can then iterate over it to use the above formula for the time weighted average?

Thank you very much for any advice in advance. My apologies if the answer is obvious I'm very new to Pine Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can obtain the time weighted average premium like so:

```
premium = request.security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT_PREMIUM", "1", close)

new_funding_period = ta.change(time("480")) != 0

var int n = na
var float premium_sum = na
var int n_sum = na

if new_funding_period
    n := 1
    premium_sum := premium
    n_sum := 1
else
    n += 1
    premium_sum += premium * n
    n_sum += n

predicted_TWAP = premium_sum / n_sum

current_TWAP = ta.valuewhen(new_funding_period, predicted_TWAP[1], 0)
```

However, you are limited to performing the calculation on a 1 minute chart to obtain accurate results due to being unable to reliably retrieve the values from a security call from a lower timeframe when the chart is set to a higher timeframe than 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using this in my funding rate calculation does indeed provide values pretty close to ones on Binance's website (https://www.binance.com/en/futures/funding-history/1). Annoyingly there are small errors when comparing the TradingView chart and the Binance website. Sometimes they're as small as +- 0.0003 but other times 0.0027. I imagine this error is due to the reason you stated. Could it be anything else like TradingView not having the same precision as the Binance website (https://www.binance.com/en/futures/funding-history/3) or is that extremely unlikely?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, i do recall having similar minor inconsistencies when trying to calculate funding rates for Bitmex years ago, i never found an explanation for it.

Comment: Fair enough I'll see how it goes with some tinkering, thanks!